# How to implement select/deselect by clicking images or icons instead checkbox using Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

I want to click on image/icon and select or deselect the images/icons just like if it were a checkbox. How to do this using angular2+ ?

Comment: Have fun and learn something, use the [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface !

Answer (score 0):

Set a **boolean** property to the item and

Try this:

```
(click)="item.selected = !item.selected
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component and implement the interface `DefaultValueAccessor` which it will be your hook into reactive forms. Then, with styles you can mark icons/images selected as you want (ie: change bg color).